# Send mail with SMTP adapter with retry, retryinterval and delivery notification

Tags: smtp, biztalk

I have an orchestration that receives an XML with some email properties(like: to, from, cc, subject, etc..).

Then I want to send the emailmessage with a dynamic port (and I assigned some of the values according the input xml). After the email has been sent, I want to do some further processing but that processing may only execute when the mail has been delivered succesfully on the SMTP server.

In the functional design they want to have a retry per hour and maximum of one day, after that periode a message must be in the EventLog when it cannot be delivered successfully.

Therefore I set the dynamic port with the context properties BTS.RetryCount to 23 and BTS.RetryInterval to 60.

I have set the dynamic SMTP port delivery notification to "Transmitted" and I have a catch exception block to catch the DeliveryFailureException.

Is this enough ?

It is a litte bit confusing for me reading several blogs if I should mark the scope Synchronized...

Answer (score 0):

Patrick,

You're right, the documentation on this aspect of BizTalk delivery notification is scarce and confusing. After extensive testing, I have not been able to identify a difference wether the Scope is set to `Synchronized = true;` or not.

The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee294373%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) for the `Synchronized` setting only applies to shared variables when used in both branches of a Parallel execution.

As for the Delivery Notification itself, I'm currently facing a problem in production where the `FILE` adapter produces its `ACK` event before the entire contents of the file is written to the output folder - it renders this part of the solutiong useless!